# How to make each button send applicant details to a matching job record?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Without wasting time on a long intro, I have a major issue: I am currently stuck at one particular place in my project where a user can search for a job by entering keywords. After doing so, user will see matching jobs posted with an option to apply by clicking a button that is next to that job.

Here is the problem: **how do I make each button correspond to THAT particular job and post the applicants details to an appropriate row in the database, say, where `Job_ID = xyz`?**

This was the approach that I tried - assigning a unique `Job_ID` to a button based on the job that the button is linked to (making that the "name" of the button), but I have no idea how to pass that on and actually use it to achieve a result.

Help would be seriously appreciated. I have been stuck on this for a while now.

Here is my PHP code (embedded inside HTML) that outputs the search results in a table:

```
    <?php

        if (!empty($_POST['search-submit'])) {
            if (!preg_match("[/^$|\s+/]", $keywords)) {
                echo "<tr><td>" . "<b>Job Title</b>" . "</td><td>" . "<b>Job Description</b>" . "</td><td>" . "<b>Job Date</b>" . "</td></tr>";

                foreach ($search_query as $row) {
                    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['JobTitle'] . "</td><td>" . $row['JobDescription'] . "</td><td>" . $row['JobDate'] . "</td><td>" . '<input class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm" type = "submit" value = "Apply" name = ' . $row['Job_ID'] .'>' ."</td></tr>"; 
                }
            } elseif (preg_match("[/^$|\s+/]", $keywords)) {
                echo "<p>" . "No matches found." . "</p>";
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: You can add a hidden field inside the form that set the ID of the JOB _ID if you are using multiple Forms for each apply button. Instead if the button can be converted to a text link where you can pass the ID as query string

Comment: Use form for each Row of search results, add a hidden field for JOB id and place your apply button. The form action can read the hidden value when the action on the form is executed

Comment: Thank you, I will try that!

Comment: Don't edit your question to say it was solved, post an answer containing what you did to fix the issue and accept your answer once you can.

Comment: My bad! I will post the solution shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add a form for each loop of the result produced from the search query and add a hidden field with the Job_ID attribute as its value.

Based on which button is clicked, the value assigned to the hidden field would be posted and later on accessible by default queries such as $_POST['name_of_field'].

```
<?php
  if (!empty($_POST['search-submit'])) {
    if (!preg_match("[/^$|\s+/]", $keywords)) {
      echo "<tr><td>" . "<b>Job Title</b>" . "</td><td>" . "<b>Job Description</b>" . "</td><td>" . "<b>Job Date</b>" . "</td></tr>";

        foreach ($search_query as $row) {
          echo '<form method = "post" action = "">';

          echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "applyjob_id" value = "' . $row['Job_ID'] . '">  ';

          echo "<tr><td>" . $row['JobTitle'] . "</td><td>" . $row['JobDescription'] . "</td><td>" . $row['JobDate'] . "</td><td>" . 
                                '<input class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm" name = "applyjob" type = "submit" value = "Apply" >' ."</td></tr>"; 

          echo '</form>';
        }
    } elseif (preg_match("[/^$|\s+/]", $keywords)) {
    echo "<p>" . "No matches found." . "</p>";
    }
}

  if (!empty($_POST['applyjob'])) {
    $applyjob_id = isset($_POST['applyjob_id']) ? $_POST['applyjob_id'] : '';

    $stick_info = "UPDATE `userjob` SET `Seeker_ID` = '$seekerjobid' WHERE `userjob`.`Job_ID` = '$applyjob_id'";
    mysqli_query($conn, $stick_info);
  }

?>
```